# What is the difference between「ブームメント」 and「ムーブメント」and do they share the same connotation as "movement" in English?

Tags: meaning, spoken-language

> 少し前まで潜り屋と揶揄されていた探索者達は独自の**ブームメント**を巻き起こしているのである。

My question is to help me understand what 「ブームメント」 and「ムーブメント」 mean in Japanese using the example above. ブームメント　gives the impression of something much stronger than ムーブメント, but I don't understand what it means in the above.

Answer (score 5):

I believe ブームメント is simply a typo. Some people seem to have mixed ブーム (boom) with ムーブメント (movement) and came up with ブームメント.

Watch this video, where one *idol* accidentally said ブームメント, and was corrected by others at once.

https://youtu.be/Hl8V6vtdYIc?t=35s

Answer (score 3):

I think ブームメント can be either a simple malapromism, or an intended neology combining "boom" and "ment" of "movement." It may mean a sensational boom, but I'm not sure. The word, ブームメント isn't a standard Japanese word anyway.